# jstree Drag node is not selected

Tags: jstree

I can click on a node to select it, it marks node as selected.

Multi select works great as well.

I can then drag the selected node(s)

However, without the above mentioned selection Dragging a node does not select
it `(.bind("select_node.jstree", function (e, data)` only fires on mouseup)

If i have nodes selected and then drag another node ; these previously selected nodes are not deselected.

Basically,how do i emulate windows explorer drag and drop functionality ?

Answer (score 0):

to deselect the previously selected nodes, just call this function before selecting the current node.

```
$("#tree").jstree("deselect_all");
```

Call the above function and then go on with selecting the current node followed by your code.

Cheers!